# Convert binary to int in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I wish to convert a tensor of binary numbers, for example, [0,1,0,1,1] to an integer in tensorflow. In my case, the tensor is quite large, with a length of approximately 80 elements. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: What kind of integer are you hoping to get? 160000 bits is a bit more than will fit in a 64-bit integer. Is there some sort of batching going on?

Comment: @AllenLavoie Sorry. It is 80 bits in total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will almost certainly lead to overflows with length-80 binary Tensors, but the basic strategy would be to do a vectorized multiplication with a Tensor which has powers of two:

```
import tensorflow as tf

binary_string = tf.constant([1, 0, 0, 1, 1])

result = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(tf.reverse(tensor=binary_string, axis=[0]), dtype=tf.int64)
    * 2 ** tf.range(tf.cast(tf.size(binary_string), dtype=tf.int64)))

with tf.Session():
    print(result.eval())
```

Prints:

```
19
```